# Magic Tap Pausing Background Audio

Tags: ios, accessibility

I'm trying to figure out how to respond to magic tap while my audio playback app is in the background. I've already done all the Command Center stuff and they work as expected, but while audio is playing, magic tap from the home screen or elsewhere doesn't work.

I'm able to respond to magic tap while my app is in the foreground. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please specify Magic tap: what is this?

Comment: It's a voiceover feature. with the music app, spotify app, and most other audio apps, you can double tap with two fingers from the home screen to pause/play audio.

Comment: okay, thanks for clarification! Didn't know that -- unfortunately thus I can't help you without any knowledge about it.